# Can anyone help rewriting URL using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have some trouble rewriting my URLs using .htaccess, this is the htaccess code I have used

```
RewriteRule "^([ \w-]+)/?$" /future/topic?post=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

but it is not working

http://localhost/future/topic?post=2028&recipes-from-chef-bobby-flay-comfort-food-for-discomfiting-times

and the code for the URL:

```
 <?php   echo ("<p><a href='topic?post=$id&" . $slug .  "'>" . $title . "</a>");   ?>
```

Comment: You may need to supply some more information here for useful feedback.  Can you double-check the code for your URL?  It doesn't appear to match the format you used in your .htaccess file.  And have you verified that Apache is set to parse the .htaccess files?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing both parameters as defined in your `htaccess`. Your title parameter is missing.

correct it by doing this

```
<?php   

echo "<p><a href='topic?post=$id&title=$slug'>$title</a>";
//when using double quotes a lot of things can be based directly mostly variables

 ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no, it is not working I have tried when I search for http://localhost/future/topic/post/2028/title/recipes-from-chef-bobby-flay-comfort-food-for-discomfiting-times

Comment: Adjust your ```htaccess``` using ```[L,QSA]``` instead of  ```[L,NC,QSA]``` and apply the solution above. And also remove the double quotes around ```"^([ \w-]+)/?$"``` to look like ```^([ \w-]+)/?$``` .  Hoping it works this time

Comment: it shows server error and when I check the localhost main page it is not showing "future" folder and when I commented the RewriteRule in .htaccess then it works fine I mean with normal URL

Comment: why not  use direct redirecting?  I mean if you have ```post.php``` you could rewrite it as ```RewriteRule ^post$ post.php``` then pass your paramaters